# Scores optimization for ElasticSEarch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, full-text-search

We have a catalog of products stored in ElasticSearch.
Each document looks like this:

```
{
   'family': 'products family'
   'category': 'products category' 
   'name': 'product name'
   'description': 'product description'
}
```

We are trying to build a query that will get the fuzzy match for a search term and will score the results by the following order of fields:

- family
- category
- name
- description

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be to use multi-match query giving each field an appropriate boost.

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
           "query": "produce",
           "fields": ["family^4","category^3","name^2","description"],
           "fuzziness" :  "AUTO",
           "rewrite" : "constant_score_auto"
        }
    }
}
```

All documents which match on the same field would get the same score. 
You can change this behavior by tweaking [rewrite](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-term-rewrite.html) parameter
[Article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-scoring.html) gives further insight to this.